# Cleaner Way to Update Multiple Field Based on Condition?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Currently I am writing an application where speed is extremely important. The app processes a number of records, and at the end, I'd like to update those records that they were processed. A beta version had the following logic that worked fine:

```
string listOfIds = string.Join(", ", listOfIds.Select(q=> q.ID));
_db.ExecuteCommand(string.Format("update table set processed = 1 where id in ({1})", listofIds));
```

Where listOfIds contains a list of all of the Ids that have been processed. This works great, but now I need to set 'processed' to different values, based on what happened during the process. So I can't just set processed = 1, it's conditional. So listOfIds is actually defined like this:

```
List<CustomClass> listOfIds = new List<CustomClass>();

class CustomClass
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

My solution would be as follows. Instead of adding all of the records to the listOfIds, I'd have to add each possible value of 'status' to a separate list. Like this:

```
List<CustomClass> listOfSuccessfulIds = new List<CustomClass>();
List<CustomClass> listOfFailedIds = new List<CustomClass>();
List<CustomClass> listOfSomethingElseIds = new List<CustomClass>();
...
_db.ExecuteCommand(string.Format("update table set processed = 1 where id in ({1})", listOfSuccessfulIds ));
_db.ExecuteCommand(string.Format("update table set processed = 2 where id in ({1})", listOfFailedIds ));
_db.ExecuteCommand(string.Format("update table set processed = 3 where id in ({1})", listOfSomethingElseIds ));
```

This is certainly functional, but it seems messy. Especially if there are a large number of possibilities for 'processed' I feel like, as always, there's a better way to handle this.

Comment: This does not help the "messy", but you could concatenate the 3 commands followed by semi-colons into one string then just ExecuteCommand once. Might help a micro-bit with performance... :-)

Comment: you'll get better answers if you explain how you are getting this list of id's, and how the table (assuming it comes from one) where these id's come from relate to this other "table"

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have too many distinct values, you could use a case statement:

```
List<CustomClass> toUpdate = ...
var query = string.Format(@"
    UPDATE table 
    SET processed = CASE {0} ELSE 1/0 END
    WHERE id IN ({1})
    ",
    string.Join(
        " ",
        toUpdate.GroupBy(c => c.Status)
            .Select(g => string.Format("WHEN id IN ({0}) THEN {1}", g.Key, string.Join(",", g.Select(c => c.ID))
    ),
    string.Join(",", toUpdate.Select(c => c.ID))
);
```

This will give a query like:

```
UPDATE table
SET processed = CASE WHEN id IN (1, 2) THEN 1 WHEN id IN (3, 4) THEN 2 ELSE 1/0 END
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

If you have a large number of different ids, you may be best off generating subquery and joining to that:

```
var subQuery = string.Join(
    " UNION ALL ", 
    toUpdate.Select(c => string.Format("SELECT {0} AS id, {1} AS status", c.ID, c.Status)
);
```

Then you would execute a query like:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.processed = q.status
FROM table t
JOIN ({subQuery}) q
    ON q.id = t.id
```

Finally, if this is still generating too much text, you could insert the "table" represented by the subquery into a temporary table first (e. g. using SqlBulkCopy) and then execute the above query joining to the temporary table rather than the SELECT ... UNION ALL subquery.